# Can Nominatim use OpenMapTile's database?

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim, openmaptiles

If we're using OpenMapTiles, can we point Nominatim to OMT's database, or are the schemas different?

It is taking us quite a long time to processes the global OSM dataset for Nominatim, but we could save ourselves some time/storage/etc. if both products can share the same Postgres database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The geocoder Nominatim uses a different database scheme than a tile server. Geocoders and tile servers need slightly different data. Furthermore, for maximum performance, the data has to be pre-processed in different ways. That's why you can't use the same database for both.